# while True: try: except ValueError:

Tags: while-loop, except

I want to make a function like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number 1 - 5: "))
        print (x)
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was not a valid number. Try again..."
```

but how can I make sure that ‘x’ only will be printed if x  is between 0 – 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the exception flow, you can raise an exception when the user inputs an invalid value.

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number 1 - 5: "))
        if x < 1 or x > 5:
            raise ValueError('Input not valid')   # go to except block
        print (x)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops!  That was not a valid number. Try again...")
```

You can also write a loop without raising an exception:

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Please enter a number 1 - 5: "))
    if x < 1 or x > 5:
        print ("Oops!  That was not a valid number. Try again...")
        continue  # skip print 
    print (x)
```